# Can't load global scss variables in Vue SFCs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli

I tried to follow this tutorial to get access to a global file called variables.scss in all SFC files:
https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/

My project uses vue cli 3, so I added the following property to vue.config.js:

```js
{
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `@import "src/assets/scss/variables.scss";`
            }
        }
    },
}
```

the variables.scss file looks like this:

```
// variables.scss
$purple: #5D2D8B;
```

My component style looks like this:

```html
<!-- Datepicker.vue -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.picker {
  color: $purple!important;
}
</style>
```

But I got this error when trying to use the $purple variable

```
color: $purple!important;
        ^
Undefined variable: "$purple"
```

I've also tried to add style-resources-loader vue-cli plugin, but got the same error.
(added this when tried to use it):

```js
{
  pluginOptions: {
        'style-resources-loader': {
            preProcessor: 'scss',
            patterns: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/variables.scss')
            ]
        }
  }
}
```

It seems that on .vue files the @import statement is not applied, but in .scss files it is.

Anyone has an idea what is that about?

Comment: I'm not sure, seems like it should work -- have you tried using the `@` alias instead of `src`? `data: \`@import "~@/assets/scss/variables.scss";\``

Comment: Yeah, and it didn't work. I think it's something about the version of some lib in my project (vue is in 2.5.17). I tried to create a new project with `vue create` and apply everything exactly the same way I did in the original project, and it worked on the new one. Weird, right?

Comment: Yeah, I've had that happen to me on a few projects, glad you found a way to get it to work again! Sometimes the dependencies can have breaking updates when the version numbers aren't locked to specific versions.